# SSL certificate error while pushing to Heroku

Tags: git, ssl, heroku

Today I'm receiving this error after 'git push heroku master' command:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.heroku.com/myserver.git/': SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
```

What should I do?

Comment: Their cert expired just under two hours ago. They've tweeted about it from their status account.

Comment: "We have an issue with SSL certificates affecting http://status.heroku.com  and other services. Please follow @herokustatus for updates" - via https://twitter.com/herokustatus

Answer (score 3):

As @bcmcfc says above. They have tweeted "We have an issue with SSL certificates affecting http://status.heroku.com  and other services. Affected services are http://status.heroku.com  and deploys via git, Dropbox and Github sync. Apps are unaffected and running normally."

Comment: Now, when I try `git push heroku master`, the SSL certificate problem doesn't appear, but heroku don't start my deploy:
`Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:`

Comment: Was a heroku issue, fixed now! :D

Answer (score 0):

I opened https://git.heroku.com/myserver.git in Safari and checked "Always trust to Heroku domain" checkbox. Now it is working.

Comment: Did you change myserver.git with your repository?

Comment: Yes! I did, but can't see any change.

Comment: it says method not allowed. What to do exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully push using the ssh method, described in the docs here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#ssh-git-transport .

All you need to do is to add another remote, passing the `--ssh-git` flag. Let's assume your app is called `my-app`:

`heroku git:remote -a my-app -r my-app-ssh --ssh-git`

Then, you might need to add your keys to heroku if you haven't done so. There is an interactive tool for that:

`heroku keys:add`

Now you can push as usual, selecting the new remote:

`git push my-app-ssh master`

All done! Note: the `-r git-remote-name` flag is just used for convenience and can be left out.