# Heroku git push failing because of SSL

Tags: git, heroku

I'm not sure how to fix this error and the link provided was not helpful. I used to push my projects normally on heroku, but today it started rejecting it with the following message:

```
remote: curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
remote: More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
remote:
remote: curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
remote: establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
remote: how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile luvit app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to modulo-bot.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/modulo-bot.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/modulo-bot.git'
```

Comment: Is your system clock set correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is! I tried changing it -1h and +1h, didn't work. I suppose it's not the system clock then. Build still failing

Comment: Could you paste the full output from your deployment? So we can know what the deployment is trying to do when that happens.

Answer (score 1):

So I found on GitHub that the issue is in the framework I was using, because its license expired. I guess heroku has no fault here.

Thank you though!

(I'm not sure how to close it now)

Comment: Well spotted. +1. You can accept your own answer: that is enough for "closing" this question.

Answer (score 0):

In 2016, it was an [heroku server issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39661265/6309).
In 2017, it was because of an [older local openssh version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46866376/6309) (try and update yours): you can [test your connection here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45897981/6309).

I don't see any recent incident in [status.heroku.com](https://status.heroku.com/).
If the issue persists, try and [switch to an SSH URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39662180/6309).